# Can I set up Github repo to autoapprove and merge PRs from a specific user?

Tags: github

I'm working with hundreds of github repos (mostly Terraform) and every now and then I need to push a change all across those repos (typically version upgrade). Each has multiple branches and requires PR review before merge to master. Is there a way I can set it up so that PRs created by my automation account do not require approval before merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`hmarr/auto-approve-action`](https://github.com/hmarr/auto-approve-action) action, which you can configure to auto-approve PR from certain users.

In your case, that could allow you to push as a dedicated user PRs that will be automatically approved by this action.

Comment: That was easy :D Thank you!